# Zooming to users location iOS 8 MapKit Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios8, mapkit

I have no issues displaying a users current location, but I am having trouble trying to zoom to it. I have found a few solutions from other posts here, but nothing seems to be working. Advice is appreciated as it is highly likely that I am missing something simple.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@import CoreLocation;

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get authorization
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // Check before requesting, otherwise it might crash older versions of ios
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.userTrackingMode = YES;

}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation     *)userLocation
{
//CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
//MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 1000, 1000);
//[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


//Zoom map to users current location
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta = 0.00001;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.00001;

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

region.span = span;
region.center = location;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
    {
        if (!self.initialLocation) {
            self.initialLocation = userLocation.location;
            MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
            mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
            mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
            mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

            [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
        }

    }
```

`self.initialLocation` is an instance of `CLLocation`. This method constantly updates the user's current location and so what I would do is check to see if it is nil, which it should be off the start and then run the code to zoom in. After the first time, `self.initialLocation` will never be nil.

if you would constantly like to zoom into the the user's current location...get rid of the `if` statement.

**EDIT**

Set this in your .h file for self.initialLocation

`@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *initialLocation;`

**EDIT 2**

Remove this line

`self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];`

No need to re-initialize your IBOulet

Comment: Using the code you provided I get the following error:

Property 'initialLocation' not found on object of type 'ViewController"

Comment: Like I said in the paragraph below my code...`self.initialLocation` is an instance of CLLocation. Set a property like the one I am about to provide in your .h file of your view controller. @christlr try adding the new property I provided in your .h file.

Comment: Added, yet there was no change to map display.  Still viewing my current location and all of North America and Canada.

Comment: it show your current location right? And are you using a storyboard with IBOutlets or just custom classes? @christlr

Comment: Yes, I can see my current location and I am using a storyboard where my map is an IBOutlet.

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

Comment: Okay well in that case try getting rid of this line `self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];` in your `viewDidLoad`. You already have an IBOutlet. No need to re-initialize it.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it had to be something simple.  Now I can finally move on to more painful things like plotting PFObjects from Parse!

Comment: Haha yeah. Sometimes it really is simple stuff. PFObjects are the easy part! I haven't learned about PFGeoPoints but that may useful if you're using a map. Retrieving data from that map and translating into readable strings is the tricky part. Google and StackOverflow is your best friend!